# Pulling Movie_ID from TMDB Api

Tags: php, api, imdb, themoviedb-api

i have already installed MTDB, i have automated it with TMDB api, but i want to try something and experiment.
Using  https://www.2embed.ru/embed/tmdb/movie?id=  you can generate an embed link to stream almost any movie.
And i want to test it to see if its possible using MTDB, i have tried multiple ways to pull the TMDB Movie ID through its getVideos, but it only pulls up the key (youtube id)

This is the code used to pull up the TMDB API

```
const TMDB_IMAGE_BASE = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original';
CONST BACKDROP_BASE_URI = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280';
CONST PROFILE_BASE_URI = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185';
CONST YOUTUBE_BASE_URI = 'https://youtube.com/embed/';
CONST SERIES_ENDED_STATUS = ['Ended', 'Canceled'];
/**
 * @var Settings
 */
private $settings;

/**
 * @param Settings $settings
 */
public function __construct(Settings $settings)
{
    $this->settings = $settings;
}

/**
 * @param array $tmdbMedia
 * @return Collection
 */
public function execute($tmdbMedia)
{
    return collect($tmdbMedia)->map(function($mediaItem) {
        return $this->transformMediaItem($mediaItem);
    });
}

public function transformMediaItem($mediaItem)
{
    $type = $this->getType($mediaItem);
    if ($type === Person::PERSON_TYPE) {
        return $this->transformPerson($mediaItem);
    } else if ($type === Episode::EPISODE_TYPE) {
        return $this->transformEpisode($mediaItem);
    } else if ($type === Season::SEASON_TYPE) {
        return $this->transformSeason($mediaItem);
    } else {
        return $this->transformTitle($mediaItem, $type);
    }
}

private function transformTitle($data, $type)
{
    $releaseKey = $type === Title::MOVIE_TYPE ? 'release_date' : 'first_air_date';
    $releaseDate = $this->getReleaseDate($releaseKey, $data);
    $year = $this->getYear($releaseDate);
    $name = $this->getTitle($data);

    $transformed = [
        'id' => $this->encodeId('tmdb', $type, $data['id']),
        'is_series' => $type === Title::SERIES_TYPE,
        'type' => Title::TITLE_TYPE,
        'poster' => $this->getPoster(Arr::get($data, 'poster_path')),
        'release_date' => $releaseDate,
        'cast' => $this->getCast($data),
        'name' => $name,
        'description' => $data['overview'],
        'tmdb_vote_count' => $data['vote_count'] ?: null,
        'tmdb_vote_average' => round($data['vote_average'], 1) ?: null,
        'year' => $year,
        'original_title' => $this->getOriginalName($data),
        'popularity' => Arr::get($data, 'popularity'),
        'language' => Arr::get($data, 'original_language'),
        'certification' => $this->getCertification($data, $type),
        'countries' => $this->getCountries($data),
        'tagline' => Arr::get($data, 'tagline'),
        'budget' => Arr::get($data, 'budget') ?: null,
        'revenue' => Arr::get($data, 'revenue') ?: null,
        'runtime' => $this->getRuntime($data),
        'videos' => $this->getVideos($data, $year, $name),
        'images' => $this->transformImages($data),
        'backdrop' => $this->getBackdrop($data),
        'genres' => $this->getGenres($data),
        'imdb_id' => Arr::get($data, 'external_ids.imdb_id') ?: null,
        'tmdb_id' => $data['id'],
        'keywords' => $this->getKeywords($data),
        'season_count' => Arr::get($data, 'number_of_seasons', 0),
        'episode_count' => Arr::get($data, 'number_of_episodes', 0),
        'series_ended' => (bool) (array_search(Arr::get($data, 'status'), self::SERIES_ENDED_STATUS) !== false),
        'adult' => Arr::get($data, 'adult', false),
    ];

    if (Arr::get($data, 'seasons')) {
        $transformed['seasons'] = $this->getSeasons($data);
    }

    return $transformed;
}

/**
 * Get US certification for title.
 *
 * @param array $data
 * @param $type
 * @return string|null
 */
private function getCertification($data, $type)
{
    if ($type === Title::SERIES_TYPE) {
        $firstKey = 'content_ratings.results';
        $secondKey = 'rating';
    } else {
        $firstKey = 'release_dates.results';
        $secondKey = 'release_dates.*.certification';
    }

    $rating = collect(Arr::get($data, $firstKey, []))
        ->where('iso_3166_1', 'US')
        ->pluck($secondKey)
        ->flatten()
        ->filter()
        ->first();

    return $rating ? str_replace('tv-', '', strtolower($rating)) : null;
}

private function getCountries($data)
{
    return array_map(function($country) {
        return [
            'name' => strtolower($country['iso_3166_1']),
            'display_name' => $country['name'],
        ];
    }, Arr::get($data, 'production_countries', []));
}

private function transformSeason($data)
{
    $releaseDate = $this->getReleaseDate('first_air_date', $data);
    $type = Season::SEASON_TYPE;

    return [
        'id' => $this->encodeId('tmdb', $type, $data['id']),
        'type' => $type,
        'poster' => $this->getPoster(Arr::get($data, 'poster_path')),
        'release_date' => $releaseDate,
        'cast' => $this->getCast($data),
        'number' => Arr::get($data, 'season_number'),
        'episodes' => array_map(function($episode) {
            return $this->transformEpisode($episode);
        }, Arr::get($data, 'episodes', [])),
    ];
}

private function transformEpisode($data)
{
    $releaseDate = $this->getReleaseDate('air_date', $data);
    $type = Episode::EPISODE_TYPE;

    return [
        'id' => $this->encodeId('tmdb', $type, $data['id']),
        'type' => $type,
        'poster' => $this->getPoster(Arr::get($data, 'still_path')),
        'release_date' => $releaseDate,
        'cast' => $this->getCast($data),
        'name' => $this->getTitle($data),
        'description' => $data['overview'],
        'tmdb_vote_count' => $data['vote_count'],
        'tmdb_vote_average' => round($data['vote_average'], 1) ?: null,
        'popularity' => Arr::get($data, 'popularity'),
        'year' => $this->getYear($releaseDate),
        'episode_number' => Arr::get($data, 'episode_number'),
        'season_number' => Arr::get($data, 'season_number'),
    ];
}

/**
 * @param $path
 * @return null|string
 */
private function getPoster($path)
{
    return $path ? self::TMDB_IMAGE_BASE . $path : null;
}

private function getBackdrop($data)
{
    $backdrop = Arr::get($data, 'backdrop_path');
    return $backdrop ? self::BACKDROP_BASE_URI . $backdrop : null;
}

/**
 * @param array $data
 * @return array
 */
private function getSeasons($data)
{
    if ( ! Arr::has($data, 'seasons')) return null;

    // skip "specials" season with number of "0"
    $seasons = array_filter(Arr::get($data, 'seasons', []), function($season) {
        return $season['season_number'] !== 0;
    });

    return array_map(function($season) {
        return [
            'release_date' => $season['air_date'],
            'episode_count' => $season['episode_count'],
            'poster' => $season['poster_path'],
            'number' => $season['season_number'],
        ];
    }, $seasons);
}

/**
 * @param array $data
 * @return array
 */
private function getKeywords($data)
{
    $keywords = array_merge(
        Arr::get($data, 'keywords.results', []),
        Arr::get($data, 'keywords.keywords', [])
    );

    return array_map(function($keyword) {
        return ['name' => $keyword['name']];
    }, $keywords);
}

/**
 * @param array $data
 * @return integer
 */
private function getRuntime($data)
{
    $runtime = Arr::get($data, 'runtime', Arr::get($data, 'episode_run_time'));
    return (is_array($runtime) && ! empty($runtime)) ? min($runtime) : $runtime;
}

private function transformPerson($tmdbPerson)
{
    $syncCredits = $this->settings->get('content.automate_filmography');
    $hasCredits = Arr::has($tmdbPerson, 'combined_credits') && $syncCredits;
    $hasKnownForCredits = Arr::has($tmdbPerson, 'known_for') && $syncCredits;

    $data = [
        'id' => $this->encodeId('tmdb', Person::PERSON_TYPE, $tmdbPerson['id']),
        'name' => $tmdbPerson['name'],
        'tmdb_id' => $tmdbPerson['id'],
        'imdb_id' => Arr::get($tmdbPerson, 'imdb_id'),
        'gender' => $this->transformGender(Arr::get($tmdbPerson, 'gender')),
        'poster' => $this->getPoster($tmdbPerson['profile_path']),
        'type' => Person::PERSON_TYPE,
        'adult' => Arr::get($tmdbPerson, 'adult', false),
        'fully_synced' => Arr::get($tmdbPerson, 'fully_synced') ?: false,
        'relation_data' => [
            'character' => Arr::get($tmdbPerson, 'character') ?: null,
            'order' => Arr::get($tmdbPerson, 'order', 0),
            'department' => strtolower(Arr::get($tmdbPerson, 'department', 'cast')),
            'job' => strtolower(Arr::get($tmdbPerson, 'job', 'cast')),
        ]
    ];

    // "known_for" credits will only be returned from "search" tmdb api call.
    if ( ! $hasCredits && $hasKnownForCredits) {
        $data['popular_credits'] = array_map(function($credit) {
            return $this->transformMediaItem($credit);
        }, array_slice($tmdbPerson['known_for'], 0, 1));
    }

    if ($hasCredits) {
        $credits = array_merge(
            Arr::get($tmdbPerson, 'combined_credits.cast'),
            Arr::get($tmdbPerson, 'combined_credits.crew')
        );

        $credits = array_map(function($credit) {
            // TODO: add "skipRelations" flag to transform config
            $title = array_filter($this->transformMediaItem($credit), function($value) {
                return ! is_array($value);
            });

            $title['relation_data'] = [
                'department' => strtolower(Arr::get($credit, 'department', 'cast')),
                'job' => strtolower(Arr::get($credit, 'job', 'cast')),
                'character' => Arr::get($credit, 'character') ?: null,
                'order' => Arr::get($credit, 'order', 0),
            ];

            return $title;
        }, $credits);

        $credits = array_filter($credits, function($credit) {
            return !Arr::get($credit, 'adult') || $this->settings->get('tmdb.includeAdult');
        });

        $data['credits'] = $credits;
    }

    $optionalProps = [
        'biography' => 'description',
        'birthday' => 'birth_date',
        'deathday' => 'death_date',
        'place_of_birth' => 'birth_place',
        'known_for_department' => 'known_for',
        'popularity' => 'popularity',
    ];

    // can't set these as "null" as some data might not be contained
    // when getting people via movie/series filmography
    foreach ($optionalProps as $tmdbKey => $localKey) {
        if (Arr::has($tmdbPerson, $tmdbKey)) {
            $data[$localKey] = $tmdbPerson[$tmdbKey];
        }
    }

    return $data;
}

/**
 * @param array $tmdbTitle
 * @return array
 */
private function getCast($tmdbTitle)
{
    // cast/crew from series, movies and episodes
    $credits = array_merge(
        Arr::get($tmdbTitle, 'credits.cast', []),
        Arr::get($tmdbTitle, 'credits.crew', []),
        Arr::get($tmdbTitle, 'crew', []),
        Arr::get($tmdbTitle, 'guest_stars', [])
    );

    // "created_by" is in separate property
    if ($createdBy = Arr::get($tmdbTitle, 'created_by')) {
        $creators = array_map(function($person) {
            $person['job'] = 'creator';
            $person['department'] = 'creators';
            return $person;
        }, $createdBy);

        $credits = array_merge($credits, $creators);
    }

    return array_map(function($person) {
        return $this->transformPerson($person);
    }, $credits);
}

/**
 * @param int|null $gender
 * @return null|string
 */
private function transformGender($gender)
{
    if ($gender === 1) {
        return 'female';
    } else if ($gender === 2) {
        return 'male';
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * @param array $tmdbTitle
 * @param string $type
 * @return array
 */
private function transformImages($tmdbTitle, $type = 'backdrop')
{
    $images = Arr::get($tmdbTitle, 'images.backdrops', []);

    return array_map(function($image) use($type) {
        return [
            'type' => $type,
            'source' => 'tmdb',
            'url' => self::TMDB_IMAGE_BASE . $image['file_path']
        ];
    }, $images);
}

/**
 * @param $tmdbTitle
 * @return array
 */
private function getGenres($tmdbTitle)
{
    return array_map(function($genre) {
        return ['name' => $genre['name']];
    }, Arr::get($tmdbTitle, 'genres', []));
}

/**
 * @param array $tmdbTitle
 * @param string $titleName
 * @param int $year
 * @return array
 */
private function getVideos($tmdbTitle, $year, $titleName)
{
    $videos = Arr::get($tmdbTitle, 'videos.results', []);
    $videos = array_slice($videos, 0, 10);

    return array_map(function($video) use($titleName, $year) {
        return [
            'name' => trim($video['name']),
            'url' => self::YOUTUBE_BASE_URI . $video['key'],
            'type' => Video::VIDEO_TYPE_EMBED,
            'source' => 'tmdb',
            'category' => strtolower(Arr::get($video, 'type', 'trailer')),
        ];
    }, $videos);
}

/**
 * @param array $data
 * @return string
 */
private function getType($data)
{
    $hasSeasonNumber = Arr::get($data, 'season_number');
    $hasEpisodeNumber = Arr::get($data, 'episode_number');

    if ($hasEpisodeNumber && $hasSeasonNumber) {
        return Episode::EPISODE_TYPE;
    } else if ($hasSeasonNumber) {
        return Season::SEASON_TYPE;
    } else if (Arr::get($data, 'media_type') === 'person' || Arr::has($data, 'birthday')) {
        return Person::PERSON_TYPE;
    } else if (Arr::has($data, 'first_air_date')) {
        return Title::SERIES_TYPE;
    } else {
        return Title::MOVIE_TYPE;
    }
}

/**
 * @param Carbon $releaseDate
 * @return int|null
 */
private function getYear($releaseDate)
{
    if ( ! $releaseDate) return null;
    return $releaseDate->year;
}

private function getReleaseDate($key, $data)
{
    if ( ! isset($data[$key])) return null;
    return Carbon::parse($data[$key]);
}

/**
 * @param array $tmdbTitle
 * @return string|null
 */
private function getTitle($tmdbTitle)
{
    if (isset($tmdbTitle['title'])) {
        return $tmdbTitle['title'];
    } else if (isset($tmdbTitle['name'])) {
        return $tmdbTitle['name'];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * @param array $tmdbTitle
 * @return string|null
 */
private function getOriginalName($tmdbTitle)
{
    if (isset($tmdbTitle['original_title'])) {
        return $tmdbTitle['original_title'];
    } else if (isset($tmdbTitle['original_name'])) {
        return $tmdbTitle['original_name'];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

If you change

```
CONST YOUTUBE_BASE_URI = 'https://youtube.com/embed/';
```

to

```
CONST YOUTUBE_BASE_URI = 'https://www.2embed.ru/embed/tmdb/movie?id=';
```

and edit the getVideos pull

```
private function getVideos($tmdbTitle, $year, $titleName)
{
    $videos = Arr::get($tmdbTitle, 'videos.results', []);
    $videos = array_slice($videos, 0, 10);

    return array_map(function($video) use($titleName, $year) {
        return [
            'name' => trim($video['name']),
            'url' => self::YOUTUBE_BASE_URI . $video['key'],
            'type' => Video::VIDEO_TYPE_EMBED,
            'source' => 'tmdb',
            'category' => strtolower(Arr::get($video, 'type', 'trailer')),
        ];
    }, $videos);
}
```

to something that allows retrieval of Movie_ID, technically it would work
but the getVideo only pulls;

```
    { "id": xxx, (movie_id)
  "results": [{
      "id": "xxxxxxxxx854480003eb",  (key id)
      "iso_639_1": "en",
      "iso_3166_1": "US",
      "key": "XXXxxXXjlg",  (youtube link id)
      "name": "xxx",
      "site": "YouTube",
      "size": xxx,
      "type": "xxx"
    }
  ]
}
```

the problem here is, if you put in the first ID instead of key, it only pulls up the second id (key id) so link becomes

```
https://www.2embed.ru/embed/tmdb/movie?id=xxxxxxxxx854480003eb
```

Anyway to make it pull the movie_id?

https://www.themoviedb.org/settings/api